# Is it possible/reasonable to convert a git repo into sub-folder of another git repo?

Tags: git, git-svn

Say, I got 2 git repos: A and B. Both repos have its own commit history. Now, I would like to embed the whole history of A into B, sub-foldered as BA, and then delete the repo A. That is, the newly repo B now has the full history of A and B in one. Can I do that?

The reason I would like to do this is to merge 2 repos into one by put one repo as another repo's package (the python way), but I also like to have the complete committing history of both repos for tracking~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's quite possible to do that.  For example, see the **Subtree Merge** section of Jakub Narębski's answer here: [How do you merge two Git repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)